# Django - ModelAdmin media definition

Tags: python, django, media, django-modeladmin

I'm trying to include some CSS and JS files into the change form of an object like [specified in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions). Here are me files:

**admin.py**

```
#...
class ScribPartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  class Media:
    css = {
      'all': ('mymarkup.css',)
    }
    js = ('mymarkup.js',)

admin.site.register(ScribPart, ScribPartAdmin)
#...
```

**models.py**

```
class ScribPart(models.Model):
  part = models.IntegerField()
  sequence = models.IntegerField()
  file = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/')
  text = models.TextField()
#...
```

My 2 media files are included in the `change_list` template but not in the `change_form` one.

The question is: Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because I was not pointing to the good locations:

```
#...
class ScribPartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  class Media:
    css = {
      'all': ('css/mymarkup.css',)
    }
    js = ('javascript/mymarkup.js',)

admin.site.register(ScribPart, ScribPartAdmin)
#...
```

is better.

Apparently Django includes medias that are not found by the collector into the `change_list` page but not into the `change_form` page. I don't know why (or i'm missing something else)...